# WPF MediaElement Download File While Playing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mediaelement

Is there anyway to play a file (video or audio type) from server using MediaElement and at the same time save data to a specific file location , so that next time once can load directly from local system.In my project i am using WPF Media Element

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way. It's possible - there are at least two ways you could do it. But it's not easy.

It's tricky to meddle with how `MediaElement` handles its source stream, because it uses Windows Media Player internally (which means that it's using either MediaFoundation or DirectShow under the covers, depending on which version of Windows you're running). The 'obvious' solution of writing some sort of interceptor that relays the underlying stream while also saving it to disk is possible, but you have to leave the world of .NET to do it, because `MediaElement` won't work with a .NET stream.

That's not to say that it's impossible. You 'simply' have to write a custom source filter, and set it up with a custom protocol implementation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms787558(VS.85).aspx describes how the video rendering infrastructure goes about deciding what kind of object to create to represent the video source, based on the URL passed in. `MediaElement` passes the source URL directly into this underlying infrastructure, so if you write a custom filter and associate it with, say the `myhack:` protocol, then if you set the source to, say, `myhack://whatever`, it'll end up loading your filter. If you then make your filter a wrapper around the `http:` filter, you will be able to save a copy of the incoming data out to disk.

This is non-trivial.

An alternative may be to host a local HTTP server. If you have the option to open up a local socket that you can listen on, then you could write an HTTP implementation that uses one of .NET's built-in HTTP client types to fetch the data, while saving a copy and serving that data up. This is also non-trivial, but possibly easier than writing a custom source filter.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I set the file size of the downloading file before i start downloading, then the `MediaElement` will play the whole video/audio while it's downloading.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient() {Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(25)})
using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(theDownloadUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
using (var videoFileStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)) {
    videoFileStream.SetLength(response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault());
    var copying = response.Content.CopyToAsync(videoFileStream);
    //await Task.Delay(1000);
    MediaSource = fileName;
    await copying;
}
```

Comment: I've been searching for days, this is the simplest and fastest solution! Thanks man!